# Synchronizing Objects in Different Threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Right now in Qt I am faced with the problem where I have 2 threads that have 2 different objects. These objects are not QObjects, thus they are not able to communicate using Signals/Slots. The first thread is the primary thread, and the second thread is in a infinite loop, which process command objects using a queue.

The main thread must wait for the processing thread to finish the request.

How would I go about synchronizing the two different threads without using global mutex, and wait conditions?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you have a situation like this: Thread1 receives data and passes it to Thread2 for processing and waits for Thread2 to finish before reading the next data piece?

Comment: yeah its exactly the case, but synchronization is an issue since signal/slots is not an option

Comment: If thread1 doesn't move until thread2 finished processing data it just received why do you need multithreading?   All you need is one thread of Receive->Process

Comment: yeah I have homework on new years :S. Trying to hack a solution, not redesign the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use mutexes. Lock everytime you pull "request" from queue, and lock everytime you want to append to queue. This way you may have

something like this:

```
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>

class processingThread
{
public:
    void appendToQueue(Request req)
    {
       sync.lock();
       queue.append(req);
       sync.unlock();
       cond.wakeAll();            
    }

protected:
    void run()
    {
        while(1)
        {
           sync.lock();
           QWaitCondition wait(&sync);
           Request current = queue.takeFirst();

           // process request

           sync.unlock()
        }
    }

private:
    QList<Request> queue;
    QMutex sync;
    QWaitCondition cond;
};
```

You can now call processingThread::appendToQueue from any thread and get data synchronized. You can use this pattern to sync any data within thread. Just remember to lock any access to data you want sync. Note that QWaitCondition is only to make your thread work only when needed

Comment: I think using QWaitCondition is the way to go. In my solution I made that so both thread access the single objects and then they are able to synchronize using the QMutex, and the WaitCondtion. I will post a snap shot of the sample code, when I have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your command object can contain a "sync" object, so the sender can wait on this object and the processor thread can signal when it has finished.  The sync object only needs a boolean and a QWaitcondition, which shouldn't be global.